# Scroll on TableView with Trackpad

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, ios-simulator

is it possible to scroll on a tableview in the simulator with the trackpad without clicking it actually? It gets very annoying at some time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the three finger drag by follow, but it may case some delay.

> 1. From the Apple menu, choose System Preferences.
> 2. Click the Accessibility icon.
> 3. Choose Mouse & Trackpad from the options on the left.
> 4. Click Trackpad Options.
> 5. Place a checkmark next to "Enable dragging."
> 6. From the related pop-up menu, choose “three finger drag” so there's a checkmark next to it.
> 7. Click OK.

From: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204609